# Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2019 Community is unable to publish my project to Azure Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, visual-studio-2019

I am attempting to publish my solution to Azure Container Registry but am getting an error of:

```
Error response from daemon: No such image <image name:latest>

A diagnostic log has been written to the following location:
```

Output from log:

```
Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerCommandException: Running the docker.exe tag command failed.
Error response from daemon: No such image: basket.api:latest
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerOperations.ThrowDockerCommandError(String dockerCommand)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerOperations.<DockerTagAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.Docker.DockerPublish.<DockerPublishAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.ContainerRegistry.ManageContainerRegistry.<PushImageAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.Azure.Publish.PublishProviders.ContainerRegistryProfileVisual.<PostPublishAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Publish.Framework.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__202.MoveNext()
===================
```

Has anyone else run into this issue? If so is there a solution or anything that people have done to be able to send Azure Container Registry? For what it is worth I have also attempted to publish my solution w/ Docker file to Docker hub and ran into the same error.

Comment: Can you provide the command you use to push the image?

Comment: @CharlesXu - I was using the publish functionality from within Visual Studio 2019 Community edition ... and pushing to both a new and existing Azure Container Registry as well as Dockerhub with the same result. I have also disabled the `tag` from :latest to having the system generate a new one, which did not result in any difference. WIthin the Log it seems to be related to the fact the tag is not applying correctly. I am unable to disable the tag functionality however...

Comment: I have a test, but it does not give any error. Do you follow the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/deploy-docker-hub?view=vs-2019)? Maybe you need to provide more information to solve  the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Docker to work on Windows 10 you need the Pro or Enterprise Edition of Windows 10.

If you do not have one of these editions, that would explain the error.

Comment: I have Windows 10 Pro.